# How to import modules from other folders

Tags: python, init

I would like to import modules from another folder and test them.
My directory looks like this:

```
- relative_imports:
    - folder1:
        - file1.py
            - class one_1(): ...
            - class one_2(): ...
        - file2.py
            - class two_1(): ...
            - class two_2(): ...
    - folder2:
        - file3.py
```

In `file3.py` I would like to import classes: `one_1`, `one_2`, `two_1`, `two_2`. From `file1.py` and `file2.py`. I want to be able to access and test these classes.

I would not like to use the sys path method, but I would rather work with relative paths from the point of view of `file3.py`.

I have tried several variations of the following code with no success.

```
from relative_imports.folder1.file1 import one_1

val = one_1()
```

I have also tried using `__init__.py` files but I seem to have not found the correct method of importing the modules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: make sure each subdirectory has a `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly, you want to access classes from a module present in a different folder.

You can do this easily by aliasing.

scenario:
You want to access a class from file1.py in folder1 and use that data inside folder2 file3.py

```
file1.py

class ADDITION():
  def __init__(self):
      pass
  
  def addTwoNumbers(self,number1, number2):
      return numner1 + number2

global addition
addition = ADDITION()
```

No, If you would like to import the ADDITION class into file3.py

```
file3.py

from file1 import addition

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(addition.addTwoNumbers(10,20))
```